# Приложение не знает метод execute(SendMessage)

Tags: java, maven, telegram-bot

Почему приложение не признает метод `execute`?

> The method execute(SendMessage) is undefined for the type MyAmazingBot

Если вместо него использовать метод
`sendMessage` то приложение будет работать. Вообще не совсем понимаю из какого класса эти методы.
Использую `Maven`

```
package com.nw.telegrambot.lesson1;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        MyAmazingBot bot = new MyAmazingBot();
        try{
             botsApi.registerBot(new MyAmazingBot());
        }catch(TelegramApiRequestException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}




package com.nw.telegrambot.lesson1;

import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

public class MyAmazingBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "MyAmazingBot";
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
            String message_text = update.getMessage().getText();
            long chat_id = update.getMessage().getChatId();
            SendMessage message = new SendMessage().setChatId(chat_id).setText(message_text);
             try {
                 execute(message);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return "457587853:AAFV2VdF9Tp2daZF3tSVQRfeMQnhZtTIJ3A";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

потому что не существует метода execute который принимает `SendMessage` или его предков.

```
TelegramLongPollingBot -> DefaultAbsSender  -> AbsSender
```

только в `AbsSender` есть метод `execute` и выглядит он так:

```
 public <T extends Serializable, Method extends BotApiMethod<T>> T execute(Method method) throws TelegramApiException
```

вы отправляете туда `SendMessage`, который является:

```
SendMessage -> BotApiMethod -> PartialBotApiMethod -> PartialBotApiMethod
```

т.е. не существует метода, который пример SendMessage или любой из его предков. Метод который вы пытаетесь вызвать принимает аргумент `Method`.

---

Можете попробовать воспользоваться `Deprecated` методом

```
@Deprecated
public final Message sendMessage(SendMessage sendMessage) throws TelegramApiException {
    if (sendMessage == null) {
        throw new TelegramApiException("Parameter sendMessage can not be null");
    }

    return sendApiMethod(sendMessage);
}
```

либо посмотреть в документацию, как пользоваться новым api

Comment: Значит в репозиториях на Гитхабе откуда я взял этот код используется старый api? Например здесь https://github.com/silvanheller/mensa-bot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/silvanheller/mensabot/core/MensaBot.java

Comment: @НиколайБеляков я не знаю, какая версия api там, но библиотека, которую вы используете тут https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots Можете выяснить версию у автора вашего гитхаба и использовать его.

Comment: Как не существует метода execute() который принимает sendMessage если приведенный мною пример работает? Но на этот раз у меня метод execute() не работает с SendPhoto

Comment: @НиколайБеляков он существует, но помечен аннотацией Deprecated, т.е. может быть удален в дальнейшем

Answer (score -1):

Я использовал Maven, а теперь создал проект java и добавил "баночки" telegram api с зависимостями. Так приложение работает норм.

Comment: Вроде всё-таки ответ - пересоздать приложение заново...

Comment: Да я пересоздал приложение заново и оно работает.